# How do I prevent my link from appearing as referral in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I want to place a link on website A to another website B. I don't want website B to be able to see website A as referral in their Google Analytics.

I thought bit.ly might hide me link as referral, but that doesn't work.  It only masks where the link is pointing, but doesn't prevent the referrer from showing.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This will work to prevent most browsers from passing referrer info:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Put it at the top of every page where you don't want the links on that page to pass referrer info.

[More info in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer).

Comment: This doesn't work on all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy

Is there any service like bit.ly that does that?